# TensorFlow serving in java - multiple predictions in one session run

Tags: java, tensorflow, deep-learning, prediction, tensorflow-serving

i have a saved model which i manage to load ,run and get prediction for 1 row of 9 features. (input)
now i'm trying to predict 100 rows like that ,
but when trying to read the results from Tensor.copyTo() to a result array i'm getting incompatible shapes

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot copy Tensor with shape [1, 1] into object with shape [100, 1]
```

obviously i managed to run this one prediction in loop - but this is 20 times slower than the equivalent python execution of 100 in one run.

here is the saved model info as reported by /saved_model_cli.py

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['input'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 9)
        name: dense_1_input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['output'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: dense_4/BiasAdd:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

The question is - do i need to run() for every row i want to predict like the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599008/tensorflow-java-api-1st-prediction-time-vs-2nd-or-more)

Comment: You cannot feed an array of shape `[100,1]` on the CNN because its first layer is fixed, you cannot change it. My first guess would be that you have to `run()` for each row, but the Java implementation of Tensorflow looks pretty screwed up, I cannot get a proper example to show that

Comment: OK answering myself here.
According to the official tensor flow for JAVA examples - the run() is per prediction.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/languages/java/object_detection/src/main/java/DetectObjects.java

Comment: i didnt mention it but the reaaon for the question was that java runs 20 times slower than python. and this is weird to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK , so i found the problem i wasn't able to run once for all the rows(predictions) i wanted. probably a tensorflow newbie issue that i messed up with input and output matrix.
when the report tool (python) say that you have a input Tensor
with shape (-1,9) which map to java long[]{1,9} it does not mean you cannot pass input as long[]{1000,9} - this means 1000 rows for predictions.
after this input the output tensor which is defined as [1,1] can be [1000,1].

This code actually runs much faster than python(1.2 seconds vs 7 seconds)
here is the code (maybe will explain better)

```
public Tensor prepareData(){
    Random r = new Random();
    float[]inputArr = new float[NUMBER_OF_KEWORDS*NUMBER_OF_FIELDS];
    for (int i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_KEWORDS * NUMBER_OF_FIELDS;i++){
        inputArr[i] = r.nextFloat();
    }

    FloatBuffer inputBuff = FloatBuffer.wrap(inputArr, 0, NUMBER_OF_KEWORDS*NUMBER_OF_FIELDS);
    return Tensor.create(new long[]{NUMBER_OF_KEWORDS,NUMBER_OF_FIELDS}, inputBuff);
}

public void predict (Tensor inputTensor){
    try ( Session s = savedModelBundle.session()) {
        Tensor result;
        long globalStart = System.nanoTime();
            result = s.runner().feed("dense_1_input", inputTensor).fetch("dense_4/BiasAdd").run().get(0);

            final long[] rshape = result.shape();
            if (result.numDimensions() != 2 || rshape[0] <= NUMBER_OF_KEWORDS) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        String.format(
                                "Expected model to produce a [N,1] shaped tensor where N is the number of labels, instead it produced one with shape %s",
                                Arrays.toString(rshape)));
            }


        float[][] resultArray = (float[][]) result.copyTo(new float[NUMBER_OF_KEWORDS][1]);
        System.out.println(String.format("Total of %d,  took : %.4f ms", NUMBER_OF_KEWORDS, ((double) System.nanoTime() - globalStart) / 1000000));
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(resultArray[i][0]);
        }
    }
}
```